# Finding mutual products between two columns of R , referring to another dataframe

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, r

I am new to R , and I am trying to write R script to find mutual products between two places. The table structure of my two tables look like this:

Table1

```
OriginPlace DestinationPlace
Tampere   Turku
Turku     Helsinki
Oulu      Porvoo
```

Table2

```
Place    ProductId
Tampere  Prod1
Tampere  Prod2
Tampere  Prod3
Turku    Prod2
Turku    Prod3
Helsinki Prod2
Oulu     Prod1
Oulu     Prod2
Porvoo   Prod1
Porvoo   Prod2
```

I want my resultant table to look like this:

```
OriginPlace DestinationPlace MutualProducts
Tampere     Turku            Prod2
Tampere     Turku            Prod3
Turku       Helsinki         Prod2
Oulu        Porvoo           Prod1
Oulu        Porvoo           Prod2
```

The actual data is much larger. How to use the for loop effectively in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. And are those numbers just line numbers?

Comment: You could also check  ?match

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will solve the problem (assuming table1 as the first table with OriginPlace and DestinationPlace column)

```
 SELECT
   table1.OriginPlace,
   table1.DestinationPlace,
   table2.ProductId as MultiProducts
FROM table1
   join table2 on table1.OriginPlace = table2.Place
   join table2 as tb2 on (tb2.Place = table1.DestinationPlace AND 
   tb2.ProductId = table2.ProductId)
```

Comment: I am using R and did this: 

library(dplyr)
Table2a <- left_join(Table2, Table1, by = c("Place"="OriginPlace"))
Table2b <- left_join(Table2, Table1, by = c("Place"="DestinationPlace"))

Tried different options with Table2a and Table 2b to get desired result, but no luck yet. Could you help with how to get the final table in R script? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While I am using MS SQL syntax to answer this, it should work similarly for other SQL.

You need to join **table2** to **table1** twice. Once with the column ***OriginPlace***, and once with the column ***DestinationPlace*** then check where the value of ProductId is the same.

This will get you what you need:

```
select   t1.OriginPlace
    ,t1.DestinationPlace
    ,t2a.ProductId  as MutualProducts
from Table1 t1
    left join table2 t2a    on t1.OriginPlace       = t2a.Place
    left join table2 t2b    on t1.DestinationPlace  = t2b.Place
where t2a.ProductId = t2b.ProductId
```

Comment: I am using R and did this: library(dplyr) Table2a <- left_join(Table2, Table1, by = c("Place"="OriginPlace")) Table2b <- left_join(Table2, Table1, by = c("Place"="DestinationPlace")) Tried different options with Table2a and Table 2b to get desired result, but no luck yet. Could you help with how to get the final table in R script? Thanks in advance